# JSON response is null, but the URL is echoing correctly

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a form being AJAX'd in by jQuery on a page with multiple forms.  I'm performing the following function, which is a wrapper for the `$.ajax` function:

```
function do_json_get(uri){
    var ret = '';
    var url = AJAX_URL + uri;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            ret = data.html;
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    return ret;
}
```

When I go to the AJAX server directly (which is rendering the form in PHP), I get the raw JSON response - so I know the server is outputting to the browser, and the AJAX server is doing other things like setting the proper cookies, so I know that the connection is good (I get a 200 response code).  Yet the `data` object is coming back null.

Comment: It's just {'html': <RESPONSE HTML>} ... I should note that an HTML GET is also null, even though I can go to the URL again and get the properly-formed HTML on my browser.

Comment: Is your <RESPONSE HTML> encoded properly? ie. with addslashes() and the like?

Comment: Yeah - it's a real mess when you look at it in the browser.

Comment: Is the page being served from the file system, or from the same server that is sending the response?

Comment: Firefox with Firebug + Chrome.

Comment: The page is being served from the same server, but a different domain.

Comment: The different domain is likely the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a guess. If you're serving the page from the file system, Firefox (and I think Chrome) will see it as originating from a different domain. You'll get the 200 response, but no data.

Try Safari, or maybe give `jsonp` a shot in place of `json`.

**EDIT:**

Since you're getting the data from a different domain, it won't work. I think it is not allowed by the XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: I didn't realize jsonp was necessary outside of the domain.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Oh boy.  This question again.

**AJAX**: **Asynchronous** JavaScript And XML*. Asynchronous. Asynchronous. Asynchronous.

Your function, `do_json_get()` returns `ret` before the **success** handler function in the AJAX call executes.  The order of operation is not proceeding, here, from top to bottom. In other words, *you just can't do it that way.*

Because of its asynchronous nature, AJAX operates on callbacks, not return values. You need to change your paradigm.  The **success** handler function needs to do whatever is required with `data.html` itself, or pass it off to another function.

* *Yes, I know the XML part of the original acronym is largely vestigial these days*

Comment: This would be a great answer if I didn't specify async: false in the $.ajax call to avoid just such a race condition.

Comment: @b. e. hollenbeck, just because you can set `async` to `false` doesn't mean you should've in this case. Handle the JSON within the callback or employ a delegate method.

Comment: @Peter Bailey, just because you're frustrated that this is a common misconception doesn't mean you should take your anger out on the OP.

Comment: And just for the sake of completeness, I put the $.ajax inline with the rest of the function and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @macek don't assume I'm angry.  I'm not.  Anger would involve CAPS and lots of exclamations points and perhaps some expletives.  Clearly I misunderstood the problem but that doesn't mean I'm *angry* about it.